# Recommended URL structure for products and categories in MVC app?

Tags: information-architecture, urls

For example, suppose I have a site with products and product categories. I'm trying to come up with a good intuitive url structure. I want to use name slugs throughout rather than database ids. In general I'm not a fan of query string parameters (e.g., `www.example.com/products?category=tools`) so where possible I'd like to avoid them.

**Example URLS:**

product list:

`www.example.com/products`

single product:

`www.example.com/products/hammer`

this is fine and I have this working. Where it gets more complicated is where I want to add categories.

all products in a category?:

```
www.example.com/categories/furniture
www.example.com/products/furniture
www.example.com/products/by-category/furniture
```

What about new products?:

`www.example.com/products/new`

Or products under $10?:

`www.example.com/products/under-10`

What makes sense? Is there some kind of convention? Is there an article about this?  I would imagine the rails community would have covered this (although not using rails myself) but I can't find a resource.  One thing about using products/some-filter is that its competing for the same namespace as individual product listings and there is a potential for a clash.

**UPDATE**

I should add that **there is not a strong hierarchy** so it doesn't make sense for a single product to belong to a category as it can belong to many categories.  So a url such as www.example.com/tools/hammer (where hammer is a single product) wouldn't work.

When I look at this site (and other stack exchange sites) for tags they use:

`http://ux.stackexchange.com/tags`

and questions with a given tag:

`http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urls`

and a single question:

`http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/26340/recommended-url-structure-for-products-and-categories-in-mvc-app`

Treating tags as analogous to categories this would give an analogous structure of:

```
www.example.com/categories
www.example.com/products/by-category/tools
www.example.com/products/hammer
```

Comment: http://www.seomoz.org/q/best-url-structure-for-ecommerce-sites

Answer (score 2):

This is how I like to think about it, and it's the way Google suggests it in their "SEO Guide" which gives it credibility with my boss ;). You should be able to remove the end "directory" and get relevant content.

```
http://clothing.com/mens/shirts/three-wolf-moon
http://clothing.com/mens/shirts
http://clothing.com/mens
```

If you wanted some kind of filters you can do something along the lines of:

```
http://clothing.com/mens/price:0-10/color:red
```

Then, to avoid duplicate content you would just use a canonical URL for products:

```
 http://clothing.com/three-wolf-moon
```

I think these urls are the most friendly.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to draw out your hierarchical structure of your data (which I'm guessing might relate strongly with the hierarchy of your navigation); then build up your URL's based on this hierarchy.  For instance:

```
     /-- about us   
home --- contact   
     \-- products --- furniture
                  \-- tools     --- hammer
                                \-- saw
```

For filters like price range, I would suggest using parameters, because these filters are not strictly hierarchical and (like you said) would compete with a hierarchical filter like "furniture".

So in short: 
If there is a strong hierarchy use www.site.com/products/tools/hammer; and if there is not a strong hierarchy, use parameters www.site.com/products/tools?pricehigh=100.

Comment: There's not a strong hierarchy so a product could be in multiple categories.  I'd really like to avoid query parameters if possible.

Comment: I guess parameters have the advantage of easy combination of multiple filters, although I don't have a strong need for this at the moment.